# Mailservers responding 220 ********************

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

Whenever I try to connect to another mail server from my ubuntu box on port 25 I receive

220 ************************************

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that behavior when you are running the mail server behind a Cisco Pix/ASA running SMTP fixup/inspect maps. If this is the case if you turn it off the message won't be blanked out. Exchange 2003 in particular does NOT like this behavior.

Comment: Drat... I got a phone call and you beat me to it. +1...

Comment: Awesome! This was no where else on the Internet that I could find it!

Comment: @Evan: Common let other people get some rep :)
@Brian: Yea I learned the hard way about that one ... when I was consulting and the consultant on the other end kept blaming my systems for the exchange servers not being able to talk!

Comment: The postfix-users mailing list has several posts on fixup: http://groups.google.com/group/mailing.postfix.users/search?group=mailing.postfix.users&q=fixup&qt_g=Search+this+group

Answer (score 2):

To add on to the above post, this is as I understand it at least partially a security feature to prevent spammers etc. from determining the name of your mail server. You should be able to pass traffic even with a 220 response, what the Cisco Firewall fixup does is basically restrict usage commands to strict SMTP protocol standards, Have you actually tried passing traffic? We did have an instance here where turning the fixup off was necessary, but I have also seen it at other sites where it was not necessary to turn it off.

Comment: Cisco PIX SMTP fixup makes SMTP less useful by effectively disabling ESMTP. Or it did when I last looked. It's almost never necessary or useful in front of a Real MTA.